# How to fix Pixelation Issues on Kali USB

Tags: kali-linux, live-usb

I made a live installation of Kali and it works great, there’s nothing wrong with the graphics or anything. But after formatting the free space on my flash drive and making it persistent storage, kali has screen tears and colorful pixelations. 
CPU: amd ryzen 5
Graphics Card: NVIDIA GTX 1050
Here is an example:
[image: example]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @jsotola what’s causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED
Turn off the Compositor.
Window Manager Tweaks > Compositor > uncheck the first option.

(If running on vm, disable 3D acceleration)